# Trouble setting up screen sharing on Fedora 27 Desktop

Tags: fedora, vnc-server, screensharing, wayland

I'm running Fedora 27 Desktop edition with GNOME. I've tried instructions from all over the web, but haven't found anything that lets me set up sharing my screen with a remote user. Can anyone help me with this?

Thank you very much in advance for your response.

Here's the story so far:

========

I initially tried:

`Activies -> Show Application -> Settings -> Sharing`

and saw options:

```
File Sharing
Media Sharing
Remote Login
```

But saw no option for `Screen Sharing`, which one page suggested should be present.

========

I've looked at:

https://docs.fedoraproject.org/f27/system-administrators-guide/Wayland.html

and run

`$ echo $WAYLAND_DISPLAY`

which yields

`wayland-0`

but I can't find out how to use this information to solve my problem. I also don't find documentation that screen sharing on Wayland under Fedora 27 is working.

========

Of the many solutions I've tried, I made the best progress by following instructions at https://docs.fedoraproject.org/f27/system-administrators-guide/infrastructure-services/TigerVNC.html

The following commands worked:

```
sudo dnf install tigervnc-server
sudo cp /lib/systemd/system/vncserver@.service /etc/systemd/system/vncserver@.service
```

Then I edited `/etc/systemd/system/vncserver@.service`, replacing `<USER>` with my user name in the following two lines:

```
ExecStart=/sbin/runuser -l <USER> -c "/usr/bin/vncserver %i -geometry 1280x1024"
PIDFile=/home/<USER>/.vnc/%H%i.pid
```

Then I ran:

`sudo systemctl daemon-reload`

and set a password with:

`vncpasswd`

Next the site's instructions told me:

> With a valid display number, execute the following command:
>
> `sudo systemctl enable vncserver@:display_number.service`

I've tried using display numbers 0, 1, and 2.

With display number as 1, for example, I got different error messages depending on whether SELinux was set to `Enforcing` or `Permissive`.

`sudo systemctl start vncserver@:1.service`

With 'Enforcing':

```
Job for vncserver@:1.service failed because the service did not take the steps required by its unit configuration.
See "systemctl  status vncserver@:1.service" and "journalctl  -xe" for details.
```

After trying the following steps suggested by SELinux:

```
sudo ausearch -c 'systemd' --raw | audit2allow -M my-systemd
semodule -i my-systemd.pp
```

and:

```
sudo ausearch -c 'geoclue' --raw | audit2allow -M my-geoclue
sudo semodule -i my-geoclue.pp
```

the error message changed to be same as given here for 'Permissive':

```
Job for vncserver@:1.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl  status vncserver@:1.service" and "journalctl  -xe" for details.
```

The output of `systemctl status vncserver@:1.service` was as follows:

```
● vncserver@:1.service - Remote desktop service (VNC)
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/vncserver@.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2018-03-26 12:24:12 EDT; 3min 4s ago
  Process: 23294 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/runuser -l jazcap53 -c /usr/bin/vncserver :1 (code=exited, status=98)
  Process: 23292 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c /usr/bin/vncserver -kill :1 > /dev/null 2>&1 || : (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Mar 26 12:24:12 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting Remote desktop service (VNC)...
Mar 26 12:24:12 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: vncserver@:1.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=98
Mar 26 12:24:12 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start Remote desktop service (VNC).
Mar 26 12:24:12 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: vncserver@:1.service: Unit entered failed state.
Mar 26 12:24:12 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: vncserver@:1.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

And `sudo journalctl -xe` produced:

```
Mar 26 12:27:41 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Started SSSD Kerberos Cache Manager.
-- Subject: Unit sssd-kcm.service has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit sssd-kcm.service has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is done.
Mar 26 12:27:41 localhost.localdomain audit[1]: SERVICE_START pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=sssd-kcm c
Mar 26 12:27:41 localhost.localdomain sssd[kcm][23679]: Starting up
Mar 26 12:27:41 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Started SSSD Secrets Service responder.
-- Subject: Unit sssd-secrets.service has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit sssd-secrets.service has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is done.
Mar 26 12:27:41 localhost.localdomain audit[1]: SERVICE_START pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=sssd-secre
Mar 26 12:27:41 localhost.localdomain sssd[secrets][23680]: Starting up
Mar 26 12:30:04 localhost.localdomain sudo[23858]: jazcap53 : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/jazcap53 ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/journalctl -xe
Mar 26 12:30:04 localhost.localdomain audit[23858]: USER_CMD pid=23858 uid=1001 auid=1001 ses=3 subj=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 msg
Mar 26 12:30:04 localhost.localdomain audit[23858]: CRED_REFR pid=23858 uid=0 auid=1001 ses=3 subj=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 msg='
Mar 26 12:30:04 localhost.localdomain sudo[23858]: pam_systemd(sudo:session): Cannot create session: Already occupied by a session
Mar 26 12:30:04 localhost.localdomain audit[23858]: USER_START pid=23858 uid=0 auid=1001 ses=3 subj=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 msg=
Mar 26 12:30:04 localhost.localdomain sudo[23858]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have `Vino` installed, GNOME will not display Screen Sharing as an option.

`sudo dnf install vino` should do it. You can then set up screenshare as per your initial attempt.

Comment: Fe 27 has reached EOL so I'm using Fe 29 now, which is letting me use screen sharing in Gnome without problems. :)